# iFrame in UIWebView loads the content of iframe inside the container UIWebView

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

Opening a page like this in UIWebView causes the WebView to load the URL that shoudl be loaded inside the iframe.... can this be changed? ie, can the WebView "stay" on the main page, and load the other page inside the iFrame?

MAIN.HTML:
(shortened for simplicity)

```
<html>
   Hello, see the content of the iframe below
   <iframe scr=iframe.html />
</html>
```

PROBLEM - UIWebView will load iframe.html, rathern than Main.Html with the iframe inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could download page and then feed UIWebView with string?